# working with variable number of arguments using scanner input class

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

While working with scanner input can we use var.. args with **sc.nextInt()**?? 
for example..(below code)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Sample
{
public static void run(int... args){
    System.out.println(args[1]);
    }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter values: ");
    int values = sc.nextInt();
    run(values);
}

}
```

the output was ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1 can any one explain about this...

Comment: Well, you pass a single integer, and you try to access the second element of the array. Array indices start at 0 in Java.

Comment: you can accept my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

`values` is just one variable, so `args`'s length is 1, which means the only valid index is 0 (arrays are zero-based entities)

Answer (score 1):

Your array size is 1 and trying to access 2nd value so use below code. I have change from `args[1]` to `args[0]`.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` arise when we try to access index value which is not present in array, not only for integers array but for all types of arrays.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
class Sample
{
public static void run(int... args){
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter values: ");
    int values = sc.nextInt();
    run(values);
}

}
```

Comment: But if i entered array of values like 1,2,3,4  at run time then args[1] is not working..can you plz clarify that

Answer (score 0):

use args[0] instead args[1] because your value store on